# Nativescript - Angular - TypeScript - RadAutoCompleteTextView - Keyboard Hides when first focus

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nativescript

I am new to RadAutoCompleteTextView and just wondering how to show the keyboard on the first time focus. In current case, it's hiding the keyboard on first focus and we need to manually click on the RadAutoCompleteTextView to view the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `layoutChanged` event listener to the component and manually focus the textfield within,

**HTML**

```
<RadAutoCompleteTextView (layoutChanged)="onLayoutChanged($event)" ....>
```

**TS**

```
import * as utils from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils;

onLayoutChanged(event) {
    const autoCompleteTextView = event.object;
    if (autoCompleteTextView.android) {
        autoCompleteTextView.android.getTextField().requestFocus();
        utils.ad.showSoftInput(autoCompleteTextView.android.getTextField());
    } else {
        autoCompleteTextView.ios.textField.becomeFirstResponder();
    }
}
```